# ¿Como podría hacer un intervalo que cada vez vaya disminuyendo un poco más hasta que se termine?

Tags: javascript

Quiero hacer un pequeño script que simule una de tirada de dados, que vaya cambiando de dado muy rápido y cada vez vaya más lento hasta que se pare, lo he intentado hacer con intervalos pero me he quedado bloqueado. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Dejo el javascript por aquí:

```
let boton = document.querySelector('button');
let h3 = document.querySelector('h3');
let dado = document.querySelector('img');

boton.addEventListener('click',function(){
    let segundosIntervaloSecundario = 300;
    
    let intervaloPrincipal = setTimeout(function(){
        
        let intervaloSecundario = setInterval(function(){

        let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6+1);
        dado.src="imgDados/"+random+".svg"
        h3.textContent="Tirada: "+random;

        },segundosIntervaloSecundario)

        let timeOut = setInterval(function(){
            clearInterval(intervaloSecundario);
            segundosIntervaloSecundario+=100;

        },1000);

    },1000)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer una función `cambiarDado` que cambie el dado y que a su vez se llame a si misma después de un intervalo de tiempo con un `setTimeout`.

```
let time = 300;
function cambiarDado(){
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    dado.src = "imgDados/" + random + ".svg"
    h3.textContent = "Tirada: " + random;

    setTimeout(_ => {
        console.log(`Dado cambiado después de ${time}`);
        time += 100;
        cambiarDado();
    }, time);
}

let boton = document.querySelector('button');
boton.addEventListener("click", _ => {
    setTimeout(_ => {
        cambiarDado();
    }, 1000);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Primer debes establecer una función que determine la velocidad del cambio. Puedes abrir la calculadora de Windows y pones el modo gráfico.

Por ejemplo yo encontré que esta podría servir (a elevado a X) con a = 1,1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que queremos es que AUMENTAR el LAPSO de tiempo que hay entre que se muestra un dado y el otro a medida que pasa el tiempo

esto en JavaScript sería

```
Math.pow(1.1,x)
```

Luego ocupamos [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) de forma recursiva, y cada vez aumentamos el tiempo de transición en base a la función anterior.

Quizás todo suena más complicado de lo que parece, pero fíjate en el código y veras que es bastante sencillo
Ejemplo:

```js
const MAX = 68;
const DADOS = ["⚀", "⚁", "⚂", "⚃", "⚄", "⚅"];

function animar(x) {
    if (x>=MAX) return;
         
    setTimeout(function () {
        Dado1.innerHTML = DADOS[getRandom()];
        Dado2.innerHTML = DADOS[getRandom()];
        animar(x+1);
    }, Math.pow(1.1,x));
}
function getRandom() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
}
```

```css
.dado{
    font-size:75px;
    display:inline-block;
}
button{
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="Dado1" class="dado"></div>
<div id="Dado2" class="dado"></div>

<button onclick="animar(1)">Lanzar dados</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Como usar setTimeout() en JavaScript**
El método setTimeout() permite ejecutar un fragmento de código, una vez transcurrido un tiempo determinado. Puedes pensar en el método como una forma de establecer un temporizador para ejecutar código de JavaScript en un momento determinado.

```js
let boton = document.querySelector('button');
let h3 = document.querySelector('h3');
let dado = document.querySelector('img');
let segundosIntervalo = 1;
let srcer=dado.src
function lazardados()
{   if (segundosIntervalo>=0)
    {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6+1);
        dado.src="https://arduinofacil.com//wp-content//uploads//2019//04//dado2.gif"
        h3.textContent="Tirada: "+random;
        segundosIntervalo +=20;
        if (segundosIntervalo <300)
        setTimeout(lazardados,segundosIntervalo)
        else
        segundosIntervalo = -1;
        setTimeout(function(){dado.src=srcer},2000)
        
    }
    else{
    
        segundosIntervalo = 0;
    setTimeout(lazardados,segundosIntervalo)
    }

}
boton.addEventListener('click',lazardados)
```

```html
<button>lanzar</button>
<h3></h3>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOMAAADaCAMAAABjJQUbAAAApVBMVEX///+1AACMAAD/AADOAAD/MDH/ICH/QUL/UVLv7+//ZWPnGBjvPDn/FBDnLCn38/f/TUrv9/fe3969vr3Oz87/eXv3TUrGICG119a1LCmMYWPe5+fW8/fWEBDGcXOlqq3n4+f/jozWsrXew8ZjMDH/hoSlFBDGUVLGnpyEhoTGiozeXVrv296tRUL/mpz/z87/pqWlw73/w8b35+chAAD/srXeoqX5mA90AAAaTUlEQVR4nO1dC2OivBIFFHyAqGgVlVqr1mqr7XYf/f8/7c5MEkggICra3e92WNTtbluOZ848QhIN49u+7du+7du+7du+7du+7du+7du+7dv+Nvs1/PP5NJ8/dr/6Qiq31n7142X+/Oy79Vq9hla/++prqshmDFrD7zBgio2++uousv375+d87vluTbCmNf/XV1/oydZ6/7nczucN/z4flmrOvwISg8jL68gHaAWc6a2z/+qrLzIIIgyaW5o1LcjhVwPJWut99QlBxHPdQqWdYMuvhiRs/758w/joVgRMts8vRdYF0j7nrw1SWvXghL18CbgVVCKv3jlB5Cy7fTXQnd7fBlpi8xtD3F8UJ8+015tCXJn1a2ovz55vCHGIEL/CvNthnNYZj7cH6vdvBPHXpv4lrkogb9RRbs26aSLI+9qR0OM22i+f2+Xy8bXhVATSvU2FfkBXRSbdmlt4PU/DCKyFD+FweVcNzJtU6N2NCTTyyFpQbPurKGAWBsMgBNu+VoJydX2MgcUggrveO/lMdobRLJjNWvDn1wJwDoeDMFzaVYD8c3WMS8CITKK73ru1PA9sRwGga5HNFoASQA4+wnmnApBXr9C3VgwRnLXj5lz0sh+0Wn1+tBazxZCB3BZruJw9XhnjzmQgOZPjmqtNI08Rg9hlVLZ+MSYfwm0VTF65Qp+bpvBWE5wVTHvRrwgRDDB2uwh1FoQrAvlSAcYrgzwAxIRJFxKIq9Nk590gFrucSwAcBAOwhw+vCpBXrdAnJjOCaEL6ACJ1TNotg1PIgS5mwRBBfsyrwHjNkdeWZVoyk+CtDsDUXESjb5CvdjmfrQVT5MeuEoy1RutaGIem0CMPO2NA6DhakFB3tYQmkdMgWCGPlQiydsXidSV4TFIIENnRMtnZGuiwxCMFoICCznNFGK82vLw1Y6szJslbHX107b3j9yCVqMxFAJE1fKkiQzK7UvFKqSNmkoMcO05H664Qeh5bLaOPfBr91iwKq2ORQF6leJ1yPSaaNF1g0tcySV/ptLc/IZHA90b7ZZvyjMv/DU9H/D948rzXkX1af3INkAfLVBWJsXVM7trRapI9Oc3XZs8uKnH8u89VuACmB9un1xNwXqF4Xcss8nIHKgHfdxyZSRfA4enAISNzM0eH/mdtFESiF4vCKPwclS75Ki9eWxuZx5hJADl2XF9hMoHgcMAEJnZU8UycjaIwELaC8j0MB6W7zarH0N8tVY+8l3Qh7Ng+Z7LD4cAJoDsOg+lS2ce/zuGLZ+g2AdsM281gxrvNIPx02Bt11CouXpemjkeTEgi5q5txyE7m0c0AbYTBYsabTUgxe95tvtZi5gut2uJ1a6b1yAuBsY+S9DHw0IFlAZ7JU4deJ69q/Bnrh9eIlX1oiDPg3ea8Jrl5AdxKi9dpikeRQiC2+sik73cklmJAncRV3TSjePj7pNPEZrMlus15TWK+wBoVYnw2OTA1R4I5wKTt26TJhC5xQG+S0BY/JG/BGxZ7fXZSt7mnbhPd1WW6Tly7o4PrV4dxkuExia0E0iNNxuAcPOmBgeQPySO5rFuzjT5rqtnZnSGTg4fBxwe+YxneNVbdyOvETLMYa/IeFOnbNoVXunyHKjw42St2uvwAYE4noRIVhZU7a8UQZMBaaug2uaoTt4/5VKxTEchWlkVet8IJ5Y6N7gqa5AxigecQOAaWw6SWk/wW2KU/wEwbmeyyTpNa6mC4om6Tu2onG5PTFlSCcWjJLipXOyzs+J5ve7YTM4i8wWvMKvy1K3FJfPLTRZAGNZo4ctCKeNiBbtNJgrIbcyoln04M970KjEsti6ID4SBtz/EFlE4MTpgM0BGPyGyt86dlxKMG3V8L1m3uapxrNClOSQ6bMFrFBJAXU9WjXO1Q2HH8BhBpO7YEzJdOTC8OJVKHk8vZxshUa6Ok2LABdpvgrOGDXcMWHFE6zP/j4p+rXiowarW3yzHO9XqMs+R47E9scldCwJ8QMUfpx7B9fBN8V3Drkyrd15+s06RRgyAMPwCiI7kpH7PG+M2BpsqDyyv0adpFU0yCt9rII/yxOU0eHDadmD3xMWZQPEucwuU/vSObfSOKFoM5sigUyw5o016Wg2E4XH7OsQdz2RsQM/l0KcZJAvG3leURQPqgyQZp0osvncARQJ+D5YxKbksvMTjBZTqN5t2Px/ZrA65Z0S9iaQyg9QrCPZzQa76MajWlFr68Qt8IUJvpbro7pHIkLwQ4jzbjj/No4wmvbM6pxC37u0RpnPhciWquXTsMsUfZQwsGTRjCfK0lGRSLogtnuSxi7g4fD2CHbL1zz0o6BtNPwHBgPudUPDOx+vywY+opHvudOP7y3NqpLcNgEHeakFwA5tauseJAMHlRhf4u4Gw+qAYJJ2kmTZZAGh5D6XCw7PQYv/zRprdCgktOzBj1ebzyU6J1nUGEXRje14RKaB8O6b7mXa0m58+LJoBsBY/TEN5BeA+XagCiwDN2yV0ZGLxwT4LFcaLbeim39fgrIdU4FGEEFkhtvHHbZePSrdkCXRayaLhFkJ1OR3Q2FwwvbwWkeTQM4BhGc8vM9JKYPrwGQ+OlaFSI9GyJXjoFaDsB7sUZiNx1GPEukxV9bMxgEC5dlychKhEvGF6G1MGY3EYQ2YJwNQs3mujq+ARS8VM7Q2T86HDl2pJiOTRbYpT+VmtHrM/scy4XULrjraItFQeOS8UQDrGcO7z8LMAMjKC1WIAiIjHeKo/u3PsTgujZaTUqRHq2xKMnvQHMyT075pGdRBR0FwSwz24xtKg/QSbvanKx6J49e3ktGBsarQW067NFfymzaPFBZQw7nt1o6HhMuW/8RcmDMcUkjirSCxNqral2mvBWU38y+LBrch51zx1eXgs4Q6Pb78IvmEXRRNEjDztjG5hs2HjkEplAyoZehWfOKndh6E8M3oRhM9bnt/zwPkri16yYOKdCX1hMjxbyyFUBJayGSZZAbIKZT6TWd+3kXwmYnZQJjNfaqyEclUVXPmKw7fAILPrUs0ZeV1aiRxIE/ApjoOslTQd49IBKMBmPTJQngZaDkCROFTm9AsC1ZsugG/EMancRYhM2eLDdJJvS8zkgmfYQ6NIQ76Ix1DXN4K4+YGQg0zwqly1hkolMR1/2T7xYqHXe+D1qOhd7mkyxFeiYw7oE8uTi9UXAsV7oXj9Kgk0QSNetWJz7CHHEUaLLguOKEx5tll1UJeowywLmoDu10Tt0Jn26BnRWqLk+nju+VCoyuJ2Ti9dprMdnI56tkSQUtQMZI5MN4a5waRh+WBhqELxGKsTYqvumSggJOGbSWqeJowYGj6xDnMHFS3ulFT+5eE1K8AnFNtRj33ixJHAJkxB2QJOMR6QSI5BkXkMCzFiWyh41RNnJexFzDRTZd+97aqijaLUdOXKXE3cy9qnF64SzCIACMWejq47xSAPLlCUbI4/DtPnpxa9TMJUwpESoBJ9Eqod3M+0edZojG+o3L+lt6DWrkkC9Jw0vbxIwKwPDGkY2Y5keEeAdiDmeoLOOGr1Gr9c4bgS3xyALViUiE5wJWg/viWFT5cpvjc1aAcfm5aB7QoUeWGTIpDWNc5RurE7E1nFjwkA2ikDaAqB8KG6bZEwFbEKx4uJ8FMJzWB/bsDvlmZSmrVibXwZPw8BjJnWIytUHiE1A0Oz18EmLNAe9BNdLHDmlTV2qlaXMfkGz4ZZeNrG1Ej1ChmQjhF1WBGg0CSA3NrorBZ4mB5M89ooANhKdxqzK2lQgqTyKl/jTe020tl26dn2RgTwbXVZqcB5TLLJecnwPdSsw2ew1R03E2kS8o16D/LfRFHgZ3BzgLFDZoiyU6wK1EhJ/YeQp1ik7JDm1YgM2VwarM/LGXMmwbkVFNvGXNohRjoLhbY7Y60Lz4pyaqofUbOKx/Jvga7fpD7zoOc8lV4ZMFRDPVDMCj8+61JF0IBglm0hZs0kOC5w26BgRkT2OEMllr0dCpxlHjmOukni4M+N3NGN03BAhmld2stLaTFjEsQDqPYzWJMug1IGMMYN44KoUd3ocHocJSaVHX0uYFChl9aZ0mtWtTW+gCo9hRIOf75ScxtNfp8DsjT5LHTn3JNk43Zhi6wjQ8F/YIyb5L88epNIe122uJboV7LVT8ARC/HFQIpTrJfeWokcL8wdO2NGqUWYSQD5j+gBwIwZMMNrsSZw2SayUagSvI+HJKqs9CWqavTvxh77ew1oZSvSyk11XSeLgx+ZluMzePE8z6WLdyvlr0mMP/ZYe2Ulf5uwmoHtCkc0k7jb5u0Avs+zdqQz2qHd13Nq47F2QrcIib7L0HKoTImh0ZzRCTTab6LQ9BlN6ZpZy2hHqlUileEToeuzMau8ueckCDWfQoXXS9ZKjdLscOGk9ajuQ0WgkQnqPn+yxIZhtNjlmTrgEl/4N3x8ErQstKYANAggQ6XYdrkMpW+dMU3rMhZxyW4ytlCVHEkgKtJL7NlOcSimm2eM+3WDf2c7F126LGGP7vssZJCtb5hxKQ8toksIOd9ZC6yUq7cW890icWed8guNOwsijqNfwnTEANIlBgli6XF2fzqIlg2SKfC0GOWLM9jjcEffbDLw7siyDDQ8AuvWEQZogVZbGbjG03BzJekmIrbGztgmoBmwOzzI4RPZ49wQHY/AuDjJUE/iOO2abMQiQuIixNI1DK2WnMTmZSIrk9iqdaagj/qwCfLx7fAK7S7kowfP8scscVDBoMhbrpeftDMo7qS66jrHNYlfdjBNYFm4Of2BPj2RPjwRR9tAmZkFg0L2vyU4aW/mhuYeTWVSCDyYQBPnK3RXbAfrTbGugSuiQPcD39vj29gYQEwbvKE30IMT4sYPGZiYv72elMc5P0aNGk/djr0HOykoTAtIUKNscucLeU5vR9/b248cPAigx2G72mlyBbk1RoILTrJ8yVj5VWTw1urIOJAk7zM8SHhlOWXtPdwzeHzh+EIOpGApVzMRBBlPUCR2y8/6EPQWmCrxT1CjqnXGsSHal4mQA1dj5hPD+/MSDA7yTAI4gyzcmPlegSp1ZV+2UtRGb8mpc/15bm0xkjUuB2F/bzbYCjzoGVB+w95OMGLzLxlCoY8Y1NxteYqjxccrgamt9HBwHNN3tdg+7aTZL3vuTZ0/SXCqxA3ugPoT3/nPxDggzAHtAoAcAx7WxqzIofDNtJy1xGf4uq8fJDqfuPHzsUuCpA+GxNd3QMoBvb3/+vL8vAOA7MPh2l4QYjLU9HOGgGHqv4DJljCbJMTkmJ0CEdr9s0tiFD4OPwfIjnKfrVguHsMhZ0/AguoD6fv5adLutPQB8A4Axfa9MgQ0bIow71udAmU8Jdv2kW8nbDIt5x5bN3RmE4SGjSexAnuMEn4QXwLfvRka3+/4OBEoOivigcwQHhRDj1O/TaFRIZqxF/nw4BaKxK8EirRmY0MydYDVczR7MdLUDWZJiK8t/T4w/cM+u0Te6oEFQ4J0KsEdlNoQYp64UammcOtgn0qimR0mPadjWNAqCcA8wV8NInQrK6h02utO+w6Ls8c/P9xbyZyzQQR8lB20zBWIERQWaGijElpliUFHjaTQmndUxPc6jxQL3rliEwWy4STOJd7M8gNh+et//eHr72e/innvgoHIEpRw/4gBTOdDUMljPvAfksCdO0VlnWNQf1rQ/w8VhC1wbFj2nWOS95KjZfnzvvj09/dn/AgeVI6jIgZ4/wRxousqla+hMmEyzWL41ZvardCk+N9iaqdZsFkRbM2W4WHICObJ9BwUo1J9v6KAxQPTQEU4I8Z2Jcz/GCGpmsOV4reYNOJHGVcLiOqNHS+HR6PI7zAuAmYy+JtEVws7rK8VVuQ+kLgL5oxxYd/U+mOQ/OYrqj+lpEKl7JB43D1DDbAp5NLrxCjgjnSNNUmTjWSQPxUE9SIEEsKZnrvBrpuK9+PrUWYE7weL242MQTQuc9mDwlSj4aAzSLIrRHWwUE3gjz/ahyB5DhNEAMVNY1BwoH2byfEJrzG3OIU4wwQ+jQz6Pm4XBd5XBG7CzTZZHc3PA+zx8ILg3GtFABQ0WmroeMPcrkhxTX8UFNSfPYBVh9TCDzBfOhgU5cmgksxKNKL0OnbvreAJx0/PpnhPyJ2fAWGtK7suwZ+awyB9Pnka2P/CoOsfF34tF9JLLo7k1kv2Purhg0tRo8h6HJ3ChxMShwd4i06RE6Q0x028IO8anQkwG5Z6N1qzVCvqzTW4imcdz6fo0Qymtx1iXdVzGnKphpDRgahk1FQbzuDytNWYWxDwabB63MqVTPaCd4cvCMLCudCyKta/1TBefy2Ihzabqzie2xsKEHin7YTBZ5eZIayCmteBMs6GqRwHYSmCmc56Zoz+VtSyDSlTdnoFxy3l8ZstNIZhkbpFLzsqmtWBk7Q/VYKMwWURRxoGzkTMVZGSoZ61ODkRcNfiMR8yY+rrV2tCsSz4La5irR65JpWrJRNJ6lilTy52qxvPWQfLearNnk7n7yqyr1LE0+Fr/PisCcqxIYDJfuqrAFG+IDuqpxbiwGR/PWfHFiSzU6nvIA9/jqZXwqJ0QoTCYo7GyWkxYhsdzN5x5IDA4Axnnrfb1y+j58WngOn8qdLa5biopUlO7KF8z42Ckd1RTglg/uTWWbC0SJNMjzT/OSSCbFl+e0BKzsNRbBMmYa47ujjGmCzXJ387fe3/A+o5fNAOZ5pDl8WiaUzZxv8XY1qvRzBKW0qMmkua7deIZl6x/ZERuefbDOdba/Eixdce6D3xjzDSTPJno4qVOdbkJIv5a8t30+pKPUGj9ZtPlqVbrJwsFdYfFknA/vYpHZfIYY6Ig0Lllrh4vW8b6QLE1YIu6aP5x/tiONYUWVR7PkcFaRTnumBJNzf+QWDQXF2Gk9VZUzkHqK+YRA8/8UMyiRod1U2KPqetYMEpxXL9056cBT5EtXpXn6pFzmQ1G2eX2uY6YZS128cyZ2ObiDRKnrC5HbzWKBjxUYHoWTYmxUikklQUzfNK/XL6BFws78HNabKrniXeTpah6TJF6do+xeEZrnDW2IhlL3oKRAH2g0fKYkqK2mjl2CAdGq+RTaXi1s5xLI+al5weY8XNKZ3rO0iwdt5NuN+bawCrvoMVMHtGgXpWyg6qvqqMxbrJOYC+tR+kC8+KnGkvlr6jgUm9bNTSKsHMxi6asP0mPOUHI3BwOk40upso/dFARRl7t6LR46rzW/KiaZumAcwx2O6tYn+f3VBlLrw84h8lToub9fBWGDwRyo+oyZRXuxSru75yvSQ3IdNZLYDyHES2qRpDpCTGSWeap96kKrXyFc4RFXUuV0tpmGXXZFpcPAHOa/j7ZKt0cmYWdfE2WU2N+Byld/iEyuouA7a7y8PDxnM+iWfHHJj2cr8dMe5zlTgKNNzP5xoi419zHJr802FSzg15i63P1aJmFXYfaXXCIAHJGG4+Eu3wWq1UjGq92yjil3nQAM6/nNCpEmwDQh5yEk/wfuKl+P3ZttVOK1Zil/O6B2zMbpiWUtIOwRo1xJ3OFDxbslqt2srOSc/WYThxYX3fjPTlaukkikk2u8dkB2WqndBiKmUw/q2wODXEXE89Ff5jPonUNGo30qlb4Xb8P6WWC+osys2FG9+rT6IoPq8Exd2Ohm1kQ03gViOlqZzKFkvJQovFS2Mu3ccTXO/Px9kCFmDBIP/NaH9iqVDubHe43F+n3g0xuAeSW42oPQTFV3MKkGw9BEYtVFuOqiSaLznVI+81FhxJjAaUsEPvN4g1dY5mFKDN5vc/d3UqXPo+CYbAPo+Eml0VTfn2siJuwbWPYPZP+vOjdsK5HoyFXO9YuChb0eQYvpfR41DYR81VcRrzcJN+l6pAf1/wEOqna2fZnM9xwLlLnCRTsumtqWJRshdkRf8nKK2CQzsqrOMWSaueFSpJZd4brsi5XIzgrrpLq77cHXVGv/szrfpBgP/5FWyOi+/9dI1rnMKgkjuxwhmp1c/w8n+dTKP3M69KYVDvJrFVxH+RyJjP/V6tF06pkw+4iE9UO272DpgGuNBAzbdXpw8M5YM3rfza0qHZoTg6BpG2vKmCxCFh8wC+uujXWGK92NkOxCWMruROSo0dhZzKpgr3FR3z3+djO0ojnrC4r0mMCSMsgO6MbYBQbJE4NsZcmfmLrET2eaVmwV+qpMsaqnU38yXJ50wWtylmEMvk2EMWksqXBPusRd0ZKOeu1WMQ5zzeyKc+Qot9TdrjKwC1i6wh7MoP0xt6KRjD6tetfYk/UwhlYVTGIx/pWH9FuYLWDIOcGW9PRz9mpLEePeQPNhTqk52u2VFljm5YGoEgKOnk8Vsri5GZaZDZMFCl4TI/YWQlMXXFQqMGMDuF3hbdFaBh84jWrA3Qf9HU6jzmg2cDKjSnkZvHaEV2Vr/1QWYx5PH4WsIiPu9tTyIxtbDmhzn15eVTVA4a/Hx6+CCAar3bAXbNrsWJGj2hOz54USaeLL0QYVzvWZLrJmR54tgb5T1hfb4SxrKm7eh7T48lMzm/QJx639dFLLstk5ph+pQplW/5OMlia0ZjHE9gT37We/hUUMpsWX7ZOd0c0iCqsbO5UJTbUs3cui6TC8ntR3ch2eVCkQi6Pyax2renXB1KNWVlFytosr0NQ4e6vo5BZZhtvfulKASAX4XlgD3+XChWbatgrw6KaU1/KbXr7RTbEfaEL9HiMRVThX0whsyyRR/SoMr3e/dUUclsXFHLHHHZ6yWqwG9pAU+3oQcp5FB4325sMeVdiUwmCYPEIj6jC694ordgy+7TKETbdE4pc+O9QyGyXhVLE4vpfUaFia50idSzS8NMNx4ErtEFpPf6TFDIrSJISq+vdV1/nJRasJSh6Fv+qxvcs2+XQF6vwbxm7uMTWaoKQc6Fl7f5dFcqWV+1Yv/8TFDKbptK89R9RoWzdeH/IZN75F92KuZ7N1ooeQYX/JQq5BetkB+X/kgpVe/ht0bGe/qXDT1VYf/Aw3T38B330277t277t2/5/7H+ygZgmNhwbggAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="></img>
```